# Finding partial attribute value in Katalon

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon

Trying to find a partial attribute value. Full value is no problem.

I have `h1 class="a b c"` and want to find out, whether this `h1` has `a` as a class attribute.

Trying `WebUI.verifyMatch(findTestObject('mytest/mytest-h1'),'a', 'a.*', false, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)` and fails on finding.

Answer (score 2):

Also answered via this [Katalon Forum post](https://forum.katalon.com/t/finding-part-of-an-attribute-value/11868) (Apologies if the link is broken, in the future).

As per Mate Mrše's answer you can also try the following:

```
def attribute = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('mytest/mytest-h1'), 'class')
boolean doesAttributeExist = attribute.contains('a')

if (!doesAttributeExist) {
    // Add some logic/interaction
}
```

Since you added `FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE` the test will fail regardless of the condition.

Should you want the test to continue rather use `FailureHandling.OPTIONAL`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def attribute = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('mytest/mytest-h1'), 'class')
assert attribute.contains('a ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, create an object using the CSS class as the locator and verify the element exists:

```
assert WebUI.verifyElementClickable(findTestObject('mytest/mytest-h1-a')) == true
```